# Nhibernate throws "Could not initialize proxy - no Session" when called many times quickly

Tags: nhibernate, session, proxy, initialization

I am having a problem with the NHibernate default fetching behavior:

**Lazy Fetching**

*Lazy fetching lets you decide how much of the object graph is loaded in the first database hit and which
associations should be loaded only when they’re first accessed. Lazy fetching is a foundational concept in
object persistence and the first step to attaining acceptable performance.*

definition from: Nhibernate In Action, 2008

***The problem:***

I have a Submit button for example and I click it many times. On the server-side, I retrieve objects through navigating the object graph, for example:

```
User us = new GetUserById(userId);
if (us.Address.Street != null)
```

where One User has one Address on the DB Schema.

The first click works correctly, but if I click it quicker it thows the exception:
**"Could not initialize proxy - no Session." Nhibernate**

Is there any work around for this behavior?

thanks,

Tito Morais

Comment: this error is thrown when you access lazy loaded properties after you closed the session. maybe you have a race condition, where one clickaction closes the session of another clickaction?

Comment: You need to update the question to show how you manage opening / closing the session. As in the previous comment, this is likely the key to solving your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use eager loading. see the below link:

http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/lazy-loading-eager-loading.html